# Clic Automático Vídeo de YouTube

Tags: javascript, jquery, youtube

Estoy trabajo un PopUp con un video iframe embebido, cuando carga la página se abre el modal el cual tiene un video de YouTube, requiero que este se reproduzca de forma automática.

Ya intente diferentes acciones mediante JQuery pero no me funciona:

```html
$('.ytp-large-play-button').click();
```

También utilice los eventos OnLoad pero el video de YouTube no se reproduce de inmediato.

Alguno conoce una solución ?

Answer (score 2):

No puedes acceder a un `<iframe />` por la [política de CORS](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Security/Same-origin_policy). Pero Youtube ya te da una solución para esto. Puedes leer la [documentación de la API en su página](https://developers.google.com/youtube/player_parameters#autoplay).

Tienes que añadir al `src` del `<iframe />` lo siguiente:

> autoplay=1&mute=1

Te quedaría un src parecido a lo siguiente

> https://www.youtube.com/embed/VIDEO_ID?autoplay=1&mute=1

Básicamente lo que hace es decirle a Youtube que quieres que se reproduzca automáticamente, pero solo puedes hacerlo si también le dices que el video tiene que estar muteado, por política de ellos.

Answer (score 0):

Gracias a ShiroiYami probe como me indicaste pero aún así no me funcionaba, me diste una idea y revise la documentación que me compartiste y configure el Link con otro extra de código.

```html
?autoplay=1&mute=1&loop=1
```

De esta forma si me reproduce de forma automática y sale en silencio, pero cumple con mi necesidad actual.

Gracias